# Extract lexicons from trained model in sentiment analysis

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, pre-trained-model, lexicon

Is there any approach I can use to extract the learned lexicons with their polarities from the trained model on sentiment analysis?

I trained Arabert model to perform the sentiment analysis on Arabic reviews. Now, I want to extract the lexicon from the trained model.

If this can't be done this with deep learning models, can I train another traditional machine learning model to extract the lexicons?

Comment: Can you explain your motivation? And also which model you are using.

Comment: @DarrenCook sure, I updated my question